# React-native JS Debugger issues with CORS — iOS

Tags: react-native, localhost, remote-debugging

I am having an issue with the react-native JS debugger on the iOS. The error occurs when I try to debug my app using the JS Debugger tool. I tried different solutions around the web with no success. Has anyone come across this error and managed to fix it?

Replication:

1) Run development app on real iOS device, which loads the JS bundle from http://172.16.23.27.xip.io:8081/index.delta?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false

2) Enable JS Remote debug tools, which opens http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ in Chrome.

3) Bundle reloads, and Chrome DevTools console displays the following error:

**Failed to load http://172.16.23.27.xip.io:8081/index.delta?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
(index):188 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch**

```
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.52.1"
```

Comment: Did you try this chrome extension?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en
It automatically adds CORS to response header.

Comment: @robi Thank you. I believe this has solved the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use `http://172.16.23.27.xip.io:8081/debugger-ui/` for debug.

or

1. open `/node_modules/metro/src/Server\index.js`
2. find `_processDeltaRequest`

   ```
     mres.setHeader(FILES_CHANGED_COUNT_HEADER, String(output.numModifiedFiles));
     mres.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
     mres.setHeader('Content-Length', String(Buffer.byteLength(output.bundle)));
   + mres.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     mres.end(output.bundle);
   ```

Comment: Awesome, that works! Just a note to anyone else - you have to restart your packager

Comment: This fix really helps me get my app running again.  It should be more upvoted.  I'm on Exp27 and the remote debugging didn't work prior to applying the above fix.

Comment: Thank you! The accepted solution only works in Chrome, this should be accepted solution.

Comment: Editing the metro server per option 2 is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: This does not exist in Expo 32.0.0

Answer (score 8):

Install [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) chrome extension. It adds CROS to response header.

Comment: I installed this but it didn't make any difference.  When I inspected with the Network tab in Chrome debugger, I didn't see any Allow-Control-... header.

Comment: The very simple fix from JRK below solved the issue for me.  You don't need this chrome extension.

Comment: This is not a solution, it doesn't work in other browsers. Using `http://IP_HERE:8081/debugger_ui/` was solution for me.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to this, if anyone is doing development on iOS then Android (or vice versa)..

If you get this message and it WAS working before; for example, I was working with an iOS project, then closed my Metro Bundler, opened cmd and built for Android. My debugger worked before with my Android project, but after this process I received the CORS issue.

Just close down the debugger tab in Chrome and open up again in the React-Native Dev Menu. Rebuild the project and hey presto! If you're in the situation where it did work, then this may the approach for you also.

Comment: I found this answer AFTER I posted my question.  This definitely does the trick.  I noticed that instead of the usual localhost:8081/debugger-ui, the address is now my local ip address:8081/debugger-ui.  Thanks for posting this!