# Not able to debug remotely for simple React-Native project

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, react-native

I created a simple project to use on a physical Iphone.  After successfully loading it on the Iphone, I was able to see the screen.  However, when I tried Remote JS Debugging.  I was given this error:

deltaUrlToBlobUrl.js:29 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://192.168.0.32:8081/index.delta?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details."

[image]

The iphone screen just shows Downloading JavaScript Bundle 100% and stays stuck on the screen without loading anything.  If I turn of Remote JS debugging, the app works normally.

How do I fix this so I can read console logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the browser address from `localhost:8081/debugger-ui/` to `http://192.168.0.32:8081/debugger-ui/` and start Remote JS debugging.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Yep!  Also I found this AFTER i posted this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445514/react-native-js-debugger-issues-with-cors-ios . The second response cleared things up nicely.