# Network Request Failed in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cors, axios, fetch

The ReactNative's `fetch` method causes `Network Request Failed` error in requesting API URL or any other resources from jordanpizza.ir.
I made a fork(https://codesandbox.io/s/5vwyq4wmnp) of react-native-web project's sandbox with this addition code at App.js:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jordanpizza.ir/test.json").then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

This sandbox reproduces my problem.

***Note:*** All resources are accessible from Postman or direct request in browser.

Comment: `"Access to fetch at 'https://jordanpizza.ir/test.json' from origin 'https://l5xz62wvwl.codesandbox.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."`
It's a cors issue, you can google how to fix it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445514/react-native-js-debugger-issues-with-cors-ios

Maybe this can help you

Comment: Thank you, I will check it. How did you find this error? @mikheevm

Comment: @mikheevm I updated the code (https://codesandbox.io/s/5vwyq4wmnp); But nothing changed

Comment: I found this error by checking the console :)

And about your code - the headers need to be set up on the server, not the client.

Comment: does the request fail on a simulator/real device?

Comment: I set the headers : `access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *` on the server too. Yes, the request fails even on real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had two aspects:

1. CORS error that solved by the @mikheevm solution.
2. DDoS protection on layer 7 provided by ArvanCloud. It blocked our requests and caused 307 redirections to be repeated, which ended when the request was canceled. This problem was also solved by clinging to the basic protection.

Answer (score 1):

Try too use this. [Cors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) Maybe that's is your problem